# Collapsible Panel in windows application

Tags: c#, window

I am trying collapsible panel.

for that I create one table layout and put 3 panels for collapsible I used following code

```
private void ButtonClick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    Label lbl = (Label)sender;

    Panel pnl = lbl.Parent;

    foreach (Panel p in TableLayoutPanel1.Controls) {
        Label l = (Label)p.Controls(0);
        if (p.Equals(pnl)) {
            //expand or collapse the panel
            if (p.Height == 150) {
                p.Height = 25;
                //Change the imaqge name to YOUR image
                l.Image = My.Resources.Expander_Collapsed16;
            } else {
                p.Height = 150;
                //Change the imaqge name to YOUR image
                l.Image = My.Resources.Expander_Expanded16;
            }

        } else {
            p.Height = 25;
            //Change the imaqge name to YOUR image
            l.Image = My.Resources.Expander_Collapsed16;
        }
    }

}
```

in that code i gor error in following three lines

```
panel pnl=lbl.Parent

Label l = (Panel)p.Controls;
```

what did i as wrong?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: For First Line gets or sets the parent container of the control

Comment: then for send line cannot covert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Controls.ControlCollection' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel'

Comment: Are you sure all controls in TableLayoutPanel1 are Panels? Are you sure all controls in each panel are Labels?

Comment: yes first i put one table layout panel with in that I put 2 cells. each cell have one panel with in panel lable listbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have done this before...not with great success but it works closing the panel

```
private void pnSearch_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReshapePanel(pnSearch);
    }

    private void ReshapePanel(Panel p)
    {
        int targetSize;
        int threshold;
        int changeDelay = 8000;
        decimal direction;

        if (p.Width == 0)
        {   //Expand
            targetSize = 200;
            threshold = 195;
            direction = 1;
        }
        else
        {   //Contract
            targetSize = 1;
            threshold = 5;
            direction = 2;
        }

        do
        {
            if (pnSearch.Width > threshold)
            {
                pnSearch.Width = targetSize;
            }
            else
            {
                if (direction == 2)
                {
                    pnSearch.Width = pnSearch.Width + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    pnSearch.Width = pnSearch.Width - 1;
                }

                //pnSearch.Width = pnSearch.Width + parse.int(1 * direction);
                Task.Delay(changeDelay);
            }

        } while (pnSearch.Width != targetSize);
    }
```